# sybase trigger conditional exec stored proc

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

I have a trigger on a table that needs to execute a stored proc if a certain condition is met.  Is there an easy way to do this without relying on creating tables to store the data in or using a cursor?

As an example I have tableA:

```
tableA
col1  INT,
col2  INT
```

On the update it needs to execute a stored proc if col2 has been updated and pass col1 as a parameter.

So it would be something like

```
CASE WHEN i.col2 <> d.col2 THEN EXEC sp_MySproc i.col1
FROM inserted i
INNER JOIN deleted d
   on i.col1 = d.col1
```

The database and all the triggers were designed for updating one record/row at a time and I'm trying to slowly make some modifications in order to have it be based on recordsets as opposed to single rows.

Would incorporating functions help with this?

Thanks

Comment: there is no direct way of doing this. However, you can loop through inserted/deleted, check and call SP inside the loop

Comment: I was trying to avoid the whole cursor thing.  I didn't think it was possible, but figured I'd see if there was something of which I wasn't aware.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Sybase ASE you could try to use construction at the trigger:

```
if update (column_name)
```

If you could refactoring your SP - you could unload data into temporary table (or physical table), and execute procedure from trigger, which will be work with this data.